# Starting Redis cluster hangs when calling redis-trib

Tags: docker, redis

I have tried to setup a Redis cluster running docker but it hangs when I try to join them. My `docker ps` gives me this:

[image: docker ps output]

Notice the port mapping.

All containers have this basic redis.conf file

```
port 6379
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes

cluster-announce-ip 127.0.0.1
cluster-announce-port [7001, 7002, 7003, 7004, 7005 or 7006]
cluster-announce-bus-port [7101, 7102, 7103, 7104, 7105 or 7106]
```

Where the only change is the `cluster-announce-port` and `cluster-announce-bus-port` for each docker container. I hope you get the point.

I try to join the nodes with `./redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 127.0.0.1:7001 127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005 127.0.0.1:7006`

And it discovers it perfectly and asking if the config should be accepted:

[image: redis-trib output]

But then `redis-trib` hangs indefinitely with "Waiting for the cluster to join". I can see through `docker logs r_1` to r_6, that the epoch is getting set:

> 1:M 15 Jul 10:38:08.493 # configEpoch set to 1 via CLUSTER SET-CONFIG-EPOCH

So `redis-trib` does call the different nodes.

I cant really find anything about the cluster-announce variables anywhere. Does anyone here know how to do this? I think my problems lies in this part.

The redis version I am using is 4.0.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. I needed to

1. set my cluster-announce-ip to the Ethernet adapter that has been created when installing docker (open up a terminal and do ipconfig)
2. update `redis-trib.rb` to reflect this IP
3. map the 16379 port when the docker image is created